# "spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^10.0.0" installing error

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-medialibrary

[

Problem 1
- spatie/image[2.2.2, ..., 2.2.5] require league/glide ^2.2.2 -> satisfiable by league/glide[2.2.2, 2.2.3].
- spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.7.9, ..., 10.8.0] require maennchen/zipstream-php ^2.0 -> satisfiable by maennchen/zipstream-php[2.0.0, ..., v2.4.0].
- spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.0.0, ..., 10.3.6] require illuminate/bus ^9.0 -> found illuminate/bus[v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.6] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.8).
- spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.4.0, ..., 10.7.8] require illuminate/bus ^9.18 -> found illuminate/bus[v9.18.0, ..., v9.52.6] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.8).
- league/glide[2.2.1, ..., 2.2.3] require psr/http-message ^1.0 -> found psr/http-message[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1] but the package is fixed to 2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- maennchen/zipstream-php[2.0.0, ..., v2.4.0] require psr/http-message ^1.0 -> found psr/http-message[1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1] but the package is fixed to 2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.9.0, ..., 10.9.1] require spatie/image ^2.2.2 -> satisfiable by spatie/image[2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5].
- Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-medialibrary ^10.0.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-medialibrary[10.0.0, ..., 10.9.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkhf9.png)

i updated composer and illumnate bus / i also tried to used other versions of spaties like vesion 9 or 8 note i am using laravel 10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.